# How to pass state from component to another external component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a state (`stateRegister`) that has `{username, email, password}` stored in component called **BasicForm.js**:

```
const BasicForm = () => {
  const [stateRegister, setStateRegister] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
  })

  function handleChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value
    setStateRegister({
      ...stateRegister,
      [e.target.name]: value,
    })
    console.log(stateRegister)
  }

  return ( //... )
}
```

I want to pass its data to an other component **Review.js**:

```
export default function Review() {
    //call and use passed stateRegister data here
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: You may want to try `useContext()`, you can learn more about it from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: i could , but i dont need to pass state to the whole app

Comment: With `useContext` you can wrap only the component you need with the provider, that way it won't be available to the entire app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either use useContext() or pass it as a prop. (so something like:

```
function BasicForm () {
...
return (<Review stateRegister={stateRegister} />)
}


function Review ({ stateRegister }) { ... }
```